# PHP: Spaces are not shown in the right place

Tags: php

This is my program I expect the output of this program is to be like *  Increasing order but the spaces are not printed....

```
    *
  *  *
 *  *  *
* * * * *

<html>
<body>
<?php
$s = '|';
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
{   
    $c=10-$i;
    for($k=1;$k<=$c;$k++) {
            echo '';
    }
    for($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++)
    {

        echo "*";
            echo ' ';
    }
    echo '<br>';
}

?>
</body>
<html>
```

I am getting this output:

```
*
* *
* * *
* * * *
* * * * *
* * * * * *
* * * * * * *
* * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * *
```

---

How do I print the spaces?

Comment: Why don't you use CSS ?

Comment: Add the CSS `white-space: pre` to the container element.

Comment: @Rimjhim Ratnani : My solution in 2 times shorter ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `&nbsp;` to add space in your code..

```
$s = '|';
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
{   
    $c=10-$i;
    for($k=1;$k<=$c;$k++) {
            echo '&nbsp;';
    }
    for($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++)
    {

        echo "*";
            echo '&nbsp;';
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
```

**Output**

```
         * 
        * * 
       * * * 
      * * * * 
     * * * * * 
    * * * * * * 
   * * * * * * * 
  * * * * * * * * 
 * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * *
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `&nbsp;` special character to print space

Try edit your `echo ' ';` on `echo '&nbsp;';`

Answer (score 1):

instead of    line "`echo ' ';`"

user `echo ""&nbsp;";"`

```
 &nbsp;
```

code is html for space

Answer (score 1):

Try This..

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$s = '|';
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
{   
    $c=10-$i;
    for($k=1;$k<=$c;$k++) {
            echo '&nbsp;';
    }
    for($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++)
    {

        echo "*";
            echo '&nbsp;';
    }
    echo '<br>';
}

?>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure ... but this is much shorter :)

```
<?php
$s = '|';
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
{   
    $str = str_pad("*", $i, "*", STR_PAD_BOTH);
    echo str_pad($str, 10, " ", STR_PAD_BOTH);
    echo '<br>';
}
?>
```

[WORKING CODE](http://codepad.org/0UkTt51U)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `echo ' ';` put `echo "&nbsp;";`.